# Can I run rviz on ubuntu arm with hydro

Tags: robotic-arm, rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm tring to run rviz out of a beaglebone with Hydro.
I know the port is still ongoing due to missing lisp libraries, but is the rviz package  affected?

I'm asking because in the rviz user guide page there is a command for getting it out of the apt repo and I can't find the package...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110796/can-i-run-rviz-on-ubuntu-arm-with-hydro/) by [Gust](https://answers.ros.org/users/8361/gust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Beableboard runs on an arm processor.

Rviz  is likely too heavy to run on the Beaglebone.

However, you can launch rviz on a distant computer and visualise data on the distant computer using:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gust](https://answers.ros.org/users/8361/gust/) on 2013-12-16**:
Well that is a good solution too. But for the sake of the argument, why can't I find the rviz in the repo?

**Comment by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) on 2013-12-16**:
Mostly because it is too heavy to run on the beableboard, since it is useless to take time to do the port.

Some tried: http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/
but i have no echo of a succesful build.